# Setup batch files in git branches

Tags: git, file, batch-file

We have 2 git branches:

- dev65 (development for version 6.5)
- prod65 (production for version 6.5)

We do all our development / testing in the dev65 branch and then merge those changes into prod65.

What I would like to do is create 2 batch files in dev65 called:

- pulldev65.bat - pull latest code from the remote
- pushdev65.bat - push my changes to the remote

And then on the prod65 branch, I would like to create similar batch files:

- pullprod65.bat - pull latest code from the remote
- pushprod65.bat - push my changes to the remote
- mergedev65.bat - merge changes from dev65 into prod65

The rub is that I want these batch files to be committed in the branches so that all developers can use these, but don't want the *dev65.bat files to be merged into the prod65 branch when we merge all other dev changes...

I know that git doesn't really want to work this way, so are there any other recommendations?  My goal here is to try and make it less easy to screw things up with a bad merge (if devs get in the habit of only using the batch files, they won't be able to accidentally merge the wrong way, etc)...

The only way I can think of is to have each dev create these unversioned files on their local machines... workable, but not ideal... (I would rather know that the batch files they are using are correct)...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make those scripts check that they're being run in the correct branch:

```
if [ "`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`" != 'master' ]; then
    echo "Call this script from master.'
    exit 10
fi
```

This avoids problems when both scripts end up getting merged into the same branch.